# I am having problems creating my GOPATH on my mac

Tags: bash, go, directory

```
    Andres-Air:~ iivri.andre$ echo 'export GOPATH = $HOME'>> $HOME/.profile
Andres-Air:~ iivri.andre$ source $HOME/.profile
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/iivri.andre': not a valid identifier
Andres-Air:~ iivri.andre$ source $HOME/.profile
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/iivri.andre': not a valid identifier
```

I am attempting to export it to my environment but I am getting these errors. How do I ensure that created the root directory correctly ?

Comment: There should not be space between `=` , variable name and value `export GOPATH=$HOME >> ~/.profile`

Comment: @BigDataLearner This time I did not include the space, and It worked but when I entered the `source $HOME/.profile` it returned the `-bash: export: =' : not a valid identifier.` error

Comment: Open the .profile in an editor and fix the incorrect lines you've added.

Comment: @siur - JimB is right...you already have inserted lines with spaces, you will need to delete/edit those

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME' >> $HOME/.profile
```